# Directive to accept numbers and empty in text field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

Hi I use one directive to accept only numbers in my text field:

HTML:

```
 <form name="filtroForm">
    <input id="idMatricula" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="filtros.Matricula" maxlength="20" numbers-only>
...
```

Module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('sg-pbm').directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

But when I use In my controler:

```
 console.log($scope.filtroForm.$valid);
```

My expression return false if my text have no data after I type anything an delete it.

Comment: Did you tried to code : if empty string then string = 0 ?

Comment: `<input type="number" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your directive a little

```
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
          modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue == undefined) return ''
              var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
              if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                modelCtrl.$render();
              }
              return transformedInput;
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ukERogXVsfDL32e7W5c?p=preview)

This directive will not let you enter anything except numbers in your input box.